# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' when using Next Middleware

Tags: reactjs, next.js, middleware

I have a simple middleware setup that checks if the user is logged in using a boolean from the zustand store, and redirect the user to the login page accordingly. This was as per the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/middleware-relative-urls)

```
   import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
    import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";
    import { useAuthStore } from "./zustand/store";
    
    export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
      const loggedIn = useAuthStore.getState().loggedIn;
      if (!loggedIn) {
        const url = request.nextUrl.clone();
        url.pathname = "/login";
        return NextResponse.rewrite(url);
      } else {
        return NextResponse.rewrite(request.nextUrl.clone());
      }
    }
```

When i use this middleware however, I get

```
react-refresh.js?ts=1661359264454:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at react-refresh.js?ts=1661359264454:1:1)
18:41:04.842 webpack.js?ts=1661359264454:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at webpack.js?ts=1661359264454:1:1)
18:41:04.842 main.js?ts=1661359264454:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at main.js?ts=1661359264454:1:1)
18:41:04.909 _app.js?ts=1661359264454:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at _app.js?ts=1661359264454:1:1)
18:41:04.924 index.js?ts=1661359264454:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at index.js?ts=1661359264454:1:1)
18:41:04.925 _buildManifest.js?ts=1661359264454:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at _buildManifest.js?ts=1661359264454:1:1)
18:41:04.925 _ssgManifest.js?ts=1661359264454:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at _ssgManifest.js?ts=1661359264454:1:1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' while using Next.js middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73229148/uncaught-syntaxerror-expected-expression-got-while-using-next-js-middlewar)?

Comment: Question has already been asked and answered, see comment above by juliomalves

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' while using Next.js middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73229148/uncaught-syntaxerror-expected-expression-got-while-using-next-js-middlewar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by [Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' while using Next.js middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73229148/uncaught-syntaxerror-expected-expression-got-while-using-next-js-middlewar)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I applied middleware by blacklist, like this.

```
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!login|signup).*)"],
}
```

By writing this, the middleware applied to unintended requests and cause the confusing error.
By fixing to whitelist matcher, the error resolved.

```
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/", "/settings", ....],
}
```