# NextResponse.rewrite does not work (return blank page)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, middleware, nextjs-rewrites

Trying to implement maintenance mode using middleware.
If i try `NextResponse.next()` after the rewrite, website loads normally and does not go to
maintenance page. I got correct response with html page in network tab, but its not showing.

If i try redirect instead of rewrite i got `"The page isn’t redirecting properly"` from firefox which indicate that there is too much redirects.

Does my next config have some bad redirects/rewrites or this does not work?

middleware.ts

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { get } from "@vercel/edge-config";

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const isInMaintenanceMode = await get<boolean>("isInMaintenanceMode");
    if (!isInMaintenanceMode) {
      if (req.nextUrl.pathname === "/maintenance") {
        req.nextUrl.pathname = `/`;
        return NextResponse.redirect(req.nextUrl);
      }
    } else {
      req.nextUrl.pathname = `/maintenance`;
      return NextResponse.rewrite(req.nextUrl);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

next.config

```
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: { esmExternals: true },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/pages/1",
        destination: "/",
      },
      {
        source: "/1",
        destination: "/",
      },
      {
        source: "/pages/:page",
        destination: "/:page",
      },
    ];
  },
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/:page((?:10[1-9])|(?:10[0-9]{2,}))",
        destination: "/pages/100",
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: "/pages/:page((?:10[1-9])|(?:10[0-9]{2,}))",
        destination: "/pages/100",
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: "/pages/:page((?:-[0-9]+)|(?:0))",
        destination: "/pages/1",
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: "/:page((?:-[0-9]+)|(?:0))",
        destination: "/pages/1",
        permanent: true,
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

Edit: Menaged to solve it by adding a **matcher**:

```
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/:pages*"],
};
```

But it throw some random error:
`SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`

So i had to exclude all routes that use _next per this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73903823/13292884

```
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!_next|api/auth).*)"],
};
```